# Android - Delete point inside Rect

Tags: android, view, canvas

I've simply painted Rect in View at onDraw event.
How can I remove point inside it on touch Event?
I don't want to remove it all, just the specific point that the touch happened in.

Thanks

Comment: The basic Idea is to show Image located under the Rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would draw a shape using the background color over your Rect at the touch point.

Comment: but I would want to put an image under it